# Student Attendance support with fullcalendar calendar control

Tags: fullcalendar

I have a requirement where I need to book attendance of students week wise and for this I am trying to use FullCalendar. I need to display students name horizontally with week view so when teacher clicks on a column against a student, his/her attendance gets recorded to the database. 
My problem is I do not know how can I able to view students details against a week view using fullcalendar. Is this possible?

Comment: Odds are, it is possible.

Comment: Ok, if this is possible can anyone let me give the directions to start through it please?